# How to automate android app builds

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

let's assume I have an android project in IntelliJ.
Now, I am changing some details on the strings.xml resource file, and after every change I build a new apk.

I want to create a second program that will automatically build an apk file. 
I could change the parameters for the strings.xml file, and then build automatically without accessing IntelliJ, is it possible? will it only be related to Java language? or could I build it in C# or any other language as well?

I did read about Maven and Ant, but I have no idea how to use them correctly, I would like an answer that will lead me to some examples or tutorials as well, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common approach is to use three things:

- Build system (Ant, Maven or Gradle) - for Android apps Gradle is
  becoming standard
- Version Control System (e.g. Git)
- Continuous Integration Server (Jenkins, Travis or
  other)

**Gradle Build System**

When you create default project in Android Studio, you already have it created with Gradle. Android Studio also allows you to convert project from Ant to Gradle. I cannot explain you, how to use Gradle in a single post, as it can be subject for whole article or even book. Basically, you have `build.gradle` file in which you can define dependencies in your project and build configuration. You can have installed Gradle in your system, but good practice is to use Gradle Wrapper, which is a single `*.jar` file and it can be used to build your application. Once you have your project configured with Gradle, you can build it from command line as follows:

`./gradlew build`

On MS Windows:

`gradlew.bat build`

**Continuous Integration Server**

When you have your project configured with Gradle, you can push its source code to your Git repository and create a job on your Continuous Integration server, which will be responsible for building your project. Within the build, you can create an artifact with compiled `*.apk` file, execute tests and run static code analysis. You can trigger your job via Git commit hooks or via polling on Continuous Integration server. It depends on chosen technology stack, but it can be automated.

If you want a lot of customization and free solution, Jenkins CI would be a good choice, but you'll have to configure a lot of stuff by yourself and host server by yourself. In my opinion, such choice can make sense in a team projects, when you have appropriate infrastructure and time to set it up. If you want an easy configuration and you're willing to spend some money or create an open-source project, I recommend using GitHub and Travis CI. It's also a good choice for individual developers. I'm not sure how to generate artifact with `*.apk` file on Travis CI, but I suppose it can be done and you can always ask support to help you. For sure, artifact be archived in Jenkins CI job.

Comment: Hey, I've got some other questions, I did manage to automate builds with a software I wrote in C# WPF, so I actually run gradlew.bat, with the desired output I wanted.

I want to move my software online, now, of course it won't be a WPF program, but im trying to implement the idea on a web page with some online builder, that will produce me the apk.

I did upload my project to github, but how can I use it from a web page? this is the second part of your answer that is still not quite clear to me. how could I invoke the gradlew.bat file? will it need the Java environment to run?

Comment: I can tell you about Jenkins. Jenkins CI Server can be accessed from the web page by default via port: 8080. I'm not familiar with WPF, but in regular Java application, you can invoke inside the job command e.g. `./gradlew build`. In the job configuration you should have option like Windows Batch or Shell script in which you can do that. You should also have an option "archive artifacts". I'm not sure if it requires a plugin or not. In artifact option, you can pass path to generated apk: `app/build/outputs/apk/*.apk`. Jenkins requires Java, because it's written in Java.

Comment: I tried using Jenkins, and it seems quite good, although I have a question.
How could I change my *.xml file through Jenkins? with a data that I receive from an online source?

Comment: Jenkins is responsible building an application - not modifying it. If you want to automatically update `*.xml` file you should do it during compilation time. I think that the best way is to modify these files via Gradle in your `build.gradle` file. I haven't done anything like that with resources, so I cannot give you exact solution, but you can take a look at this file: https://github.com/FutureProcessing/android-debug-release-template/blob/master/app/build.gradle where we're modifying `AndroidManifest.xml` file before compilation and replacing icon. Maybe it will help you with your problem.